# Remove .listing files recursively from Windows filesystem

Tags: windows, recursion

Is there any command to recursively remove .listing files from a Windows folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the command line, run this:

```
del /s *.listing
```

You can get more info on the "del" command by running:

```
del /?
```

A quick Google search for "windows recursive delete" came up with this solution as the top hit.  See: [tech-recipes.com](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/184/recursively-delete-files-in-windows/)

Answer (score 3):

```
del /s *.listing
```